# Is there a good radixsort-implementation for floats in C#

Tags: c#, algorithm, sorting, floating-point, radix-sort

I have a datastructure with a field of the float-type. A collection of these structures needs to be sorted by the value of the float. Is there a radix-sort implementation for this.

If there isn't, is there a fast way to access the exponent, the sign and the mantissa.
Because if you sort the floats first on mantissa, exponent, and on exponent the last time. You sort floats in O(n).

Comment: Isnt radixsort conceptually thought for ints, or at least any numbers in a decimal system? remember: floats are internally stored in a dual system.

Comment: indeed, but as I describe you can do it. You first sort it on mantissa (seeing the mantissa as an integer, without using the sign). Afterwards you sort them on exponent (also a signed integer). You conclude by sorting them by sign (boolean). By running three times a radix-sort algorithm you can sort floats.

Comment: I see your point. However a O(n) sorting algorithm could be way slower than a O(nlogn) standard sort, in most cases, if n never exeeds some break even point.

Comment: Keep in mind the memory overhead for a radix sort on this large of a domain as well.  Or decreasing your memory footprint increase your sort time as well.  Right now, you have a O(kn) sort where k is already 3 at least.  Depending on how you setup your radix, it could go double digit.  Add in any float/double to int part conversion code and n is going to have to be pretty large to beat a standard nlogn sort.

Comment: I have to say, after all the work, it was really worth trying it. Thanks for asking that question, without it I would never have tried that out :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Update:**

I was quite interested in this topic, so I sat down and implemented it (using [this very fast and memory conservative implementation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_implementation/Sorting/Radix_sort)). I also read [this one](https://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm) (thanks [celion](https://stackoverflow.com/users/224264/celion)) and found out that you even dont have to split the floats into mantissa and exponent to sort it. You just have to take the bits one-to-one and perform an int sort. You just have to care about the negative values, that have to be inversely put in front of the positive ones at the end of the algorithm (I made that in one step with the last iteration of the algorithm to save some cpu time).

**So heres my float radixsort:**

```
public static float[] RadixSort(this float[] array)
{
    // temporary array and the array of converted floats to ints
    int[] t = new int[array.Length];
    int[] a = new int[array.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        a[i] = BitConverter.ToInt32(BitConverter.GetBytes(array[i]), 0);

    // set the group length to 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16
    // and see which one is quicker
    int groupLength = 4;
    int bitLength = 32;

    // counting and prefix arrays
    // (dimension is 2^r, the number of possible values of a r-bit number) 
    int[] count = new int[1 << groupLength];
    int[] pref = new int[1 << groupLength];
    int groups = bitLength / groupLength;
    int mask = (1 << groupLength) - 1;
    int negatives = 0, positives = 0;

    for (int c = 0, shift = 0; c < groups; c++, shift += groupLength)
    {
        // reset count array 
        for (int j = 0; j < count.Length; j++)
            count[j] = 0;

        // counting elements of the c-th group 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        {
            count[(a[i] >> shift) & mask]++;

            // additionally count all negative 
            // values in first round
            if (c == 0 && a[i] < 0)
                negatives++;
        }
        if (c == 0) positives = a.Length - negatives;

        // calculating prefixes
        pref[0] = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < count.Length; i++)
            pref[i] = pref[i - 1] + count[i - 1];

        // from a[] to t[] elements ordered by c-th group 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++){
            // Get the right index to sort the number in
            int index = pref[(a[i] >> shift) & mask]++;

            if (c == groups - 1)
            {
                // We're in the last (most significant) group, if the
                // number is negative, order them inversely in front
                // of the array, pushing positive ones back.
                if (a[i] < 0)
                    index = positives - (index - negatives) - 1;
                else
                    index += negatives;
            }
            t[index] = a[i];
        }

        // a[]=t[] and start again until the last group 
        t.CopyTo(a, 0);
    }

    // Convert back the ints to the float array
    float[] ret = new float[a.Length];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
        ret[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(a[i]), 0);

    return ret;
}
```

It is slightly slower than an int radix sort, because of the array copying at the beginning and end of the function, where the floats are bitwise copied to ints and back. The whole function nevertheless is again O(n). In any case much faster than sorting 3 times in a row like you proposed. I dont see much room for optimizations anymore, but if anyone does: feel free to tell me.

To sort descending change this line at the very end:

```
ret[i] = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(a[i]), 0);
```

to this:

```
ret[a.Length - i - 1] = BitConverter.ToSingle(BitConverter.GetBytes(a[i]), 0);
```

**Measuring:**

I set up some short test, containing all special cases of floats (NaN, +/-Inf, Min/Max value, 0) and random numbers. It sorts exactly the same order as Linq or `Array.Sort` sorts floats:

```
NaN -> -Inf -> Min -> Negative Nums -> 0 -> Positive Nums -> Max -> +Inf
```

So i ran a test with a huge array of 10M numbers:

```
float[] test = new float[10000000];
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < test.Length; i++)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4];
    rnd.NextBytes(buffer);
    float rndfloat = BitConverter.ToSingle(buffer, 0);
    switch(i){
        case 0: { test[i] = float.MaxValue; break; }
        case 1: { test[i] = float.MinValue; break; }
        case 2: { test[i] = float.NaN; break; }
        case 3: { test[i] = float.NegativeInfinity; break; }
        case 4: { test[i] = float.PositiveInfinity; break; }
        case 5: { test[i] = 0f; break; }
        default: { test[i] = test[i] = rndfloat; break; }
    }
}
```

And stopped the time of the different sorting algorithms:

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();

float[] sorted1 = test.RadixSort();

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("RadixSort: {0}", sw.Elapsed));
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

float[] sorted2 = test.OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Linq OrderBy: {0}", sw.Elapsed));
sw.Reset();
sw.Start();

Array.Sort(test);
float[] sorted3 = test;

sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Array.Sort: {0}", sw.Elapsed));
```

And the output was (*update: now ran with release build, not debug*):

```
RadixSort: 00:00:03.9902332
Linq OrderBy: 00:00:17.4983272
Array.Sort: 00:00:03.1536785
```

roughly more than four times as fast as Linq. That is not bad. But still not yet that fast as `Array.Sort`, but also not that much worse. But i was really surprised by this one: I expected it to be slightly slower than Linq on very small arrays. But then I ran a test with just 20 elements:

```
RadixSort: 00:00:00.0012944
Linq OrderBy: 00:00:00.0072271
Array.Sort: 00:00:00.0002979
```

and even this time my Radixsort is quicker than Linq, but *way* slower than array sort. :)

**Update 2:**

I made some more measurements and found out some interesting things: longer group length constants mean less iterations and more memory usage. If you use a group length of 16 bits (only 2 iterations), you have a huge memory overhead when sorting small arrays, but you can beat `Array.Sort` if it comes to arrays larger than about 100k elements, even if not very much. The charts axes are both logarithmized:

[image: comparison chart]
<sub>(source: [daubmeier.de](http://daubmeier.de/philip/stackoverflow/radixsort_vs_arraysort.png))</sub>

Comment: By the way that algorithm is as well usable for `double` arrays, just replace `float` by `double`, `int` by `long`, `ToInt32` by `ToInt64`, `.ToSingle` by `.ToDouble` and change `int bitLength = 32;` to 64.

Comment: Well done! I didn't expect somebody to implement this problem. Very nice code and analysis. :D

Comment: @Philip Daubmeier Can you verify my performance improved version?

Answer (score 2):

There's a nice explanation of how to perform radix sort on floats here:
http://www.codercorner.com/RadixSortRevisited.htm

If all your values are positive, you can get away with using the binary representation; the link explains how to handle negative values.

Answer (score 2):

By doing some fancy casting and swapping arrays instead of copying this version is 2x  faster for 10M numbers as Philip Daubmeiers original with grouplength set to 8. It is 3x faster as Array.Sort for that arraysize.

```
 static public void RadixSortFloat(this float[] array, int arrayLen = -1)
        {
            // Some use cases have an array that is longer as the filled part which we want to sort
            if (arrayLen < 0) arrayLen = array.Length;
            // Cast our original array as long
            Span<float> asFloat = array;
            Span<int> a = MemoryMarshal.Cast<float, int>(asFloat);
            // Create a temp array
            Span<int> t = new Span<int>(new int[arrayLen]);

            // set the group length to 1, 2, 4, 8 or 16 and see which one is quicker
            int groupLength = 8;
            int bitLength = 32;

            // counting and prefix arrays
            // (dimension is 2^r, the number of possible values of a r-bit number) 
            var dim = 1 << groupLength;
            int groups = bitLength / groupLength;
            if (groups % 2 != 0) throw new Exception("groups must be even so data is in original array at end");
            var count = new int[dim];
            var pref = new int[dim];
            int mask = (dim) - 1;
            int negatives = 0, positives = 0;

            // counting elements of the 1st group incuding negative/positive
            for (int i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
            {
                if (a[i] < 0) negatives++;
                count[(a[i] >> 0) & mask]++;
            }
            positives = arrayLen - negatives;

            int c;
            int shift;
            for (c = 0, shift = 0; c < groups - 1; c++, shift += groupLength)
            {
                CalcPrefixes();
                var nextShift = shift + groupLength;
                //
                for (var i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
                {
                    var ai = a[i];
                    // Get the right index to sort the number in
                    int index = pref[( ai >> shift) & mask]++;
                    count[( ai>> nextShift) & mask]++;
                    t[index] =  ai;
                }

                // swap the arrays and start again until the last group 
                var temp = a;
                a = t;
                t = temp;
            }

            // Last round
            CalcPrefixes();
            for (var i = 0; i < arrayLen; i++)
            {
                var ai = a[i];
                // Get the right index to sort the number in
                int index = pref[( ai >> shift) & mask]++;
                // We're in the last (most significant) group, if the
                // number is negative, order them inversely in front
                // of the array, pushing positive ones back.
                if ( ai < 0) index = positives - (index - negatives) - 1; else index += negatives;
                //
                t[index] =  ai;
            }

            void CalcPrefixes()
            {
                pref[0] = 0;
                for (int i = 1; i < dim; i++)
                {
                    pref[i] = pref[i - 1] + count[i - 1];
                    count[i - 1] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an `unsafe` block to memcpy or alias a `float *` to a `uint *` to extract the bits.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best bet if the values aren't too close and there's a reasonable precision requirement, you can just use the actual float digits before and after the decimal point to do the sorting.

For example, you can just use the first 4 decimals (be they 0 or not) to do the sorting.