# how to sort an array in C in one cycle?

Tags: c, sorting, floating-point

Is there any algorythm to sort an array of float numbers in one cycle?

Comment: I'm wondering if the intended meaning here is one pass through the array, i.e. O(n).

Comment: Do you mean a processor cycle or one cycle through the array? I don't think the former exists except on some special electrified sorting machine if such a thing exists.

Comment: You're looking for an O(1) sorting algorithm? If you find one, please tell me immediately (and don't tell anybody else)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check [Counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) 
it runs in O(N + M) time where N is the input array size and M is the sorting array size

Comment: how could you create a sorting array if the input array contained floats?

Comment: @AShelly ...given an infinite tape... :-)

Comment: Missed the float part from the question, but if you take at radix sort for float you will see how how to create a sorting array for floats, bit by bit, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2685035/is-there-a-good-radixsort-implementation-for-floats-in-c

Comment: It's at least two, not one cycle.

Comment: Btw floats are "special" ints and can be sorted using only int operations, it is a little bit finicky but it can be done. http://www.stereopsis.com/radix.html

Answer (score 5):

If you mean one pass, then no. Sorting generally requires either O(N log N). Single-pass implies O(N).

Radix sort takes O(N*k) with average key-length k. Even though it's linear time, it requires multiple passes. It is also not usually suitable for sorting floats.

Comment: only comparison-based sorting algorithms require O(N log N) time

Comment: @ruslik. yes, it has limited application. but this was hint to improve answer, because it is not full.

Comment: @Andrey: Thanks for the hint. I've amended my answer.

Comment: @Andrey: for question "as-is" it's correct and complete answer.

Answer (score 4):

Take a laptop with a quicksort program on it. Then put the laptop on a unicycle. Tada! Sorting in one cycle.

Answer (score 1):

There are some sorting algorithms that are O(n) in the best-case. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_of_algorithms).

Comment: It's easy to design a sorting algorithm that is O(n) in the *best* case though -- assert that your best case is "when the array is already sorted", run through checking that it's sorted, and if it's not, run another sorting algorithm on it. Best case analysis is rarely very interesting. "All's for the best in the best of all possible worlds", as Voltaire would say.

Comment: Leibniz said that, not Voltaire.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no algorithm that is O(n). Possibly using as many parallel computers as there are elements in your array or using quantum computers, but if you want O(n) now on a regular computer, you can forget about it.

Answer (score 0):

No.

`<aside>`@codinghorror: why must my post have >= 15 characters?`</aside>`

Answer (score 0):

Sorting algorithm "in one cycle" - I believe you mean algorithm with linear complexity. In addition to these answers you can also check [Bucket Sort Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort). It has average performance O(n+k).